# Create an array from a long list of LCIDs

Tags: php, arrays, lcid

I have a long list of LCIDs which I want to assign to each other. Here is an extract:

```
1031
1033
1034
1061
1062
1026
```

I want to end up having an array or a list which looks like this:

```
1031 => 1033
1031 => 1034
1031 => 1061
1031 => 1062
1031 => 1026
1033 => 1031
1033 => 1034
1033 => 1061
1033 => 1062
1033 => 1026
1034 => 1031
1034 => 1033
1034 => 1061
1034 => 1062
1034 => 1026
```

And so on.

Any advice on how to tackle this in PHP? Help is much aprreciated!

EDIT: I now came up with this (still not what I need but I'm getting there somehow...)

```
foreach($a_languageIDs as $lcid){

    $src_lcid = $lcid + 1024;
    $trg_lcid = $lcid + 1024;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($a_languageIDs); $i++) {

            echo "$src_lcid -> $trg_lcid\r\n";
        }
}
```

Which gives me this output:

```
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1031 -> 1031
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
1033 -> 1033
```

This at least gives me this iterated list but I still have no idea how to adapt the value of $trg_lcid.

Comment: There is no built-in function, so you'd have make a custom one. You basically need nested iterations. Have you tried to solve it yourself? While we're glad to help, you're still expected to make an effort of your own. If you have tried something unsuccessfully, please add the code and explain where and how it failed to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Though, now that I've taken a closer look, you cannot get the result you wish. Keys cannot be duplicated. The best you could get is to store an array of all other elements under one key, e.g. `1031 => [1033, 1034, ...]`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Half an hour ago I didn't have anything, really. Checking "nested iterations" brought me a bit closer, see my edit.

Comment: Ah... if you only need to print the results to the screen, then you can use the same key. You just can't create an array like that. I'll have a look.

Comment: Later I want to insert $src_lcid and $trg_lcid into a function. But for the moment I think it is ok to just echo it and then go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff) within a loop:

```php
$lcids = [1031, 1033, 1034, 1061, 1062, 1026];
$allCombinations = [];
foreach ($lcids as $lcid) {
    $allOtherLCIDs = array_diff($lcids, [$lcid]);
    foreach ($allOtherLCIDs as $otherLCID) {
        echo "$lcid -> $otherLCID<br>";
    }
}
```

How this works:

- We iterate your main array, to find combinations for each of the elements.
- We use `array_diff` to create an array that holds all the elements *except* the current one. It works by comparing the first parameter (the full array) against the second one (an array holding only the current element) and returning all the elements of the first parameter that are not present in the second parameter.
- After that we iterate the created diff and output the current element of the outer loop (main array) for every element of the diff array.

Comment: Thanks again for your input and explanation. It was very helpful. I implemented it into my code and it works like a charm :)